# How to avoid losing local Google Cloud Storage data after restarting a local App Engine app?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Now, after restarting a local App Engine app, local Google Cloud Storage data will be lost. How to avoid this?

[update] I use Java. It seems the Cloud Storage data is not saved in \war\WEB-INF\appengine-generated. When I use CTRL-C to terminate the server and restart it again, the data saved in Cloud Storage will not be found.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean a local version of the datastore?  Add a flag like this: `--datastore_path=/some/path/to/store/a/local/datastore/dev_appserver.datastore`.  It will store a local version that will persist.  Otherwise, it overwrites the temp version every time you restart the app.

Lipis is correct. There are other commands that may be more suitable. From the [Command-line arguments](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver?csw=1#Python_Command-line_arguments):

```
--storage_path=...

Path at which all local files (such as the Datastore, Blobstore files, Google Cloud    Storage Files, logs, etc) will be stored, unless overridden by --datastore_path, --blobstore_path, --logs_path, etc.
```

Comment: `--storage_path` is a better option to have everything in one place.. (it includes datastore, blobstore, etc)

Comment: I update the question detail. I use Java. There is no the storage_path option. The default path is \war\WEB-INF\appengine-generated, but when I save a large file in Cloud Storage, none of the file sizes are changed in the default path. So I guess the file is just saved in memory and not flush to disk. When I use CTRL-C to terminate the server and restart it again, Cloud Storage file will be not found.

Comment: @T.L while the languages of choice is very important.. you can always add that as a tag in your questions if not mentioned in the text.

Comment: Have anybody of you already found a solution or workaround for this issue? There must be a way to be able to read a file (using the Dev Server) that was previously save. I getting always "java.io.FileNotFoundException", apparently files uploaded to the local Cloud Storage aren't available after restarting the server

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the location of the data store in java, but it's using undocumented features.

```
dev_appserver --property=datastore.backing_store=c:/temp/ds.bin <app directory>
```

To do it with Maven , please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183935/appengine-local-datastore-location-config-for-java-devserver/24219925#24219925)

Comment: Thnaks. But the datastore data is not lost. The lost is Cloud Storage data.