# How to set individual data store per local GAE app instance?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

For testing purpose I want to start two instances of a GAE app locally. However the second instance will fail to start because there is already a lock on the local database imposed by the first instance.

```
INFO     2014-09-28 05:14:22,751 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8081
OperationalError('database is locked',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 266, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 1431, in __call__
    return self._handle_request(environ, start_response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 641, in _handle_request
    module=self._module_configuration.module_name)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub.py", line 165, in WrappedMethod
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/logservice/logservice_stub.py", line 172, in start_request
    host, start_time, method, resource, http_version, module))
OperationalError: database is locked
```

Is there any way I can specify an alternative data store location in the second instance of my app?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you start your application.

If using Java, might want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24219925/2417948).

But keep in mind your two apps won't be talking to the same datastores, so if you need data to persist between your instances, this won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I am using python